# Some tracks from my MP3 CD won't play in my car...?

Tags: audio, mp3, compact-disc

I have fabric player radio.. from the car itself , so it's supporting MP3, but sometimes , not sometimes almost always when i record a mp3 CD for my car, some tracks are not playable.. they skip to the next, i don't know why, but all the tracks are playable on my PC , but some of them are not playable in my car , the CD is MP3 recorded through NERO EXPRESS (JUKEBOX).... simple cd with 700MB... (**slowest speed**)

**I don't know what is the problem but i've tried to insert and to enter the cd again, again the same track won't play... i don't know why, it's not just with one track it's with multiple .. for exampel if the CD have 75 tracks, 10 of them cannot be playied...**

(all tracks 44.00 Khz..)

Any suggestions? I would like to know is the problem with my Car player maybe laser.. or the problem with the ripping to change other Burning Program?

But if you suggest to change a burning program for CDs, give me the bestest apps not matter ..i'll buy the app.. :D

Comment: Car radios that play mp3's have a strict set of rules for mp3 tags and file names, you need to read the owners manual for that specific radio. Most do not allow any special characters in the mp3 tag or name, this will cause it to skip any that do, this is just one rule.

Comment: Hmmm it could be possible... thats good for a one of the reasons...

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and for me the solution was (in Windows 10):

- Right-click the file and go to Properties.
- Then go to the ID-Tag tag.
- The surest option is to delete all tag info and album art as well. But you can also try to find the problem tag(s) and fix or delete them.
- Now you can copy the file to a memory stick or disc and try it in your car.

Note: If you are using a different operating system and you cannot edit the tags, you can download a tag editor from FileHippo.com for example.